# How do I get the access token without using the browser

Tags: docusignapi

When I go to the following URL in the browser with my own client_id:

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=token&scope=signature&client_id=6d1a8594-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-878e593de049&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/auth

I need to login and afterwards I get redirected to:
http://localhost:8888/auth#access_token=*myAccessToken*&expires_in=28800&token_type=bearer&state=a39fh23hnf23

Now I have a node.js application where I want to make API calls using my access token, until now I did the above manually every time to get my access token, of course, this isn't optimal. My question, therefore, is: how do I get my access token without using the browser?

Right now I have the following

```
sendRequestAccessToken(): Promise<any> {
const scope = 'signature';
const clientId = '*my client id*';
const state = 'a39fh23hnf23';
const url = `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
  response_type=token
  &scope=${scope}
  &client_id=${clientId}
  &state=${state}
  &redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/auth
`;
return this.httpService.get(url).toPromise(); }
```

The response from this function contains a lot of data, but no access token.

Comment: Auth code grant workflows require user/browser interaction every time. If you would like to be able to programmatically generate a token, you should look in to JWT / Impersonation auth, which only requires user interaction once to grant consent.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the SDK examples we have here: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node

In those samples, we have examples on how to use the tokens using the apis.